# Export functionality of Custom UI grid in Magento 2 not working

Tags: magento2, grid, magento-2.1, export, uicomponent

When I tried to export data to Csv or xml from ui grid in magento2 it says:

> 1 exception(s):
>   Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid UI Component element name: ''

I had added export button. My code is given below:

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
   <exportButton name="export_button">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">custom_order_grid.custom_order_grid.custom_order_columns.ids</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
   </exportButton>
<listingToolbar>
```

Comment: What is "selectProvider"? I don't see this setting for exportButton component.

Comment: even I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 6):

I have found the issue,

Inside columns tag, you need to have selectionsColumn .

```
<columns name="custom_order_grid_data_columns">
  <selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </selectionsColumn>
     <column name="column_name">
     .
     .
     </column>
</columns>
```

Once selectionsColumn is added the export works fine

Comment: It works fine. But I can see one more column in the grid with the checkbox(Mass action). How to fix the issuw without adding new column

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251608/magento-customer-grid-custom-attribute-cant-export-csv-and-export-xml

Answer (score 2):

Add below code in your custom grid XML

```
<container name="listing_top">
    <exportButton name="export_button">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">custom_listing.custom_listing.custom_columns.ids</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </exportButton>
</container>
```

Please visit below link for more information:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-export.html