# Magento Customer Grid Custom attribute can't export csv and export xml

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, magento2.2.6, customer-grid

Magento Customer Grid Custom attribute can't export csv and export xml, Showing error, how to add custom attributes to the customer export.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory::argumentsResolver()
>   must be of the type array, null given, called in
>   /var/www/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php
>   on line 220 and defined in
>   /var/www/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:172\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(220):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->argumentsResolver('customer_clv',
>   NULL)\n#1
>   /var/www/Magento/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Column.php(77):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('customer_clv',
>   'decimal', Array)\n#2
>   /var/www/Magento/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/MassAction/Filter.php(182):
>   Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column->prepare()\n#3
>   /var/www/Magento/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/MassAction/Filter.php(180):
>   Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filte in
>   /var/www/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php
>   on line 172, referer:
>
> customer_listing.xml file containd below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!-- /**  * Copyright © Ourmodule. All rights reserved.  *  */
--> <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">

        <column name="customer_clv" class="Ourmodule\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Customerclv">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Lifetime Value</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">81</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="predicted_average_profit" class="Ourmodule\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Customerclv">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> Transaction Value</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">82</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Ourmodule\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ClvActions">
            <settings>
                <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
            </settings>
        </actionsColumn>        

    </columns> </listing>
```

Comment: For this, first you need to display your custom_attribute in customer listing. after that when you export it will include that new filed.

Comment: I have added customer listing xml updated question

Comment: @RamkishanSuthar do yo u have nay idea about this?

Comment: I just know that you need to add that attribute in listing then it will include in your csv. Magento includes only those fields which are in visible in grid.

Comment: @RamkishanSuthar so do I have to correct my customer_listing.xml file? for export functionality

Comment: Any help, I couldn't resolve this issue.

Comment: Any news on this? I am stuck at the same part .... :/

Answer (score 2):

Please do the following steps.

1.Update your di.xml with following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   
    <type name="Magento\Ui\Model\Export\MetadataProvider">
        <plugin name="custom_customer_export" type="Namespace\Module\Model\Plugin\ModifyGridExportPlugin" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
```

2.In the ModifyGridExportPlugin add below code

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Model\Plugin;
use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
class ModifyGridExportPlugin
{
    private $logger;
    protected $_resource;
    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
       
        $this->_resource          = $resource;
    }
    public function afterGetRowData($subject, $result, $document, $fields, $options)
    {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($fields as $column) {
                if ($column === 'customer_clv') {
                    $customerId=$document['entity_id'];
                    $value="Test"
                    ................
                    ................
      
                    $result[$i] = $value;
                }
               if ($column === 'predicted_average_profit') {
                    $customerId=$document['entity_id'];
                    $value="Test"
                    ................
                    ................
      
                    $result[$i] = $value;
                }
                
            $i++;
            continue;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```