# Attributes showing values instead of their labels. Exporting in customers grid: Magento 2.3.5

Tags: customer, grid, custom-options

I Have two custom attributes in my customer grid, named **old_customer (1=>Yes,0=>No) and zone (1=>India, 2=>UK, 3=>Others )** , both attributes  is_used_in_grid is true . but while I'm exporting in to the customer gird exporting option I'll get the result like below

> **Actual Result:**
>
> [image]

> **Expected Result :**
>
> [image]

Can someone please help me on this. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please check this answer. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/329528/80124
May be it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.Create di.xml in your module [etc/di.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Ui\Model\Export\MetadataProvider">
        <plugin name="export_custmer_csv_row_data" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Plugin\ExportRowDataModification" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
```

> 2. Create Plugin Model [VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ExportRowDataModification.php]

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Plugin;

class ExportRowDataModification
{
    protected $resource;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    )
    {
        $this->resource = $resource;
    }

    public function afterGetRowData($subject, $result, $document, $fields, $options)
    {
        $i = 0;

        foreach ($fields as $column) {

            //########## example formate
            if ($column === 'your_colum_name_place_here') {
                //do your logic here
            }

            //######### in my case

            //is old customer
            if ( $column === 'is_old_customer') {
                $result[$i] = (int)$result[$i] === 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No';
            }
            // change zone value to label
            if ($column === 'zone') {
                $zoneCollection = $this->zoneCollectionFactory->create();
                $zoneCollection->addFieldToFilter('zone_id', (int)$result[$i]);
                $zone = $zoneCollection->getFirstItem()->getName();
                $result[$i] = $zone;
            }

            $i++;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Thanks, @m2dubai for the knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a module who overwritte this feature. If yes, disable it and try to re-export.